# Tab div not stretching to inline content. jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, css

I have simple jQuery tab with two tab pages.
One of them have single image and text.

If I use align=left attribute on image or css float:left, tab height is shrinking to text height. If I do not one of them text begins at the bottom of image. I do not use any additional css attributes, just ones that jQuery sets from js.

I need to put image in top left corner and text should start at the top of tab, not at the bottom of image, also if text shert, tab should stretch to image height.

Answer (score 0):

Either set the image as background image of the tab content div or whatever, and set the CSS property to background-position:left top. Or put the text in a container div, p or anything you like & set the CSS property of the container to position:relative; & position it accordingly by CSS property top:, left:. Hope this might help you.